# Configure initial heap size for java 8 VM

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jvm, heap-memory, jvm-arguments

I try to set initial application memory heap size to 2gb for java 8 VM. I add `-Xms2g -Xmx2g` in `Program Arguments` section of IntelliJ.

[image]

Then I start my application and see that the heap size is less than 1gb.
[image]

What do I miss?

Comment: I guess you should be adding it in the VM options section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "Program arguments" are the arguments passed to your `main` method, not to Java itself. Move these arguments to the "VM options" box.